# Making a vector out of array without allocation and memory copying

Tags: c++, gcc

Roughly I have this API all over the place:

```
void func(const vector<int> &vint);
```

Which is badly designed, but I need to pass to it my `int*` without allocation\copy, as I found it to be a bottleneck. (executing `memcpy` concurrently on multiple threads won't copy faster)

I thought of writing a class like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct fake_vector {
    fake_vector(T *array, size_t array_length) {
        internal_vector.set_begin(array);
        internal_vector.set_end(array + array_length);
    }
    ~fake_vector() { // let's reset our internal vector so it won't try to deallocate our memory
        internal_vector.set_begin(nullptr);
        internal_vector.set_end(nullptr);
    }
    vector<T> &get() {
        return internal_vector;
    }

    vector<T> internal_vector;
};
```

And then use it like this:

```
fake_vector<int> my_fake_vector(vint,vint_length);
process(my_fake_vector.get());
```

But I don't know how to set begin\end of a vector. This question is open-ended for solution for this `fake_vector` last puzzle or a new less-hackish solution.

Comment: refactor `func()` to take a first/last iterator pair.

Comment: @RichardHodges The API is not part of the project.

Comment: Can you instead propagate the vector requirement higher up the stack? That is, don't use a raw array in the first place?

Comment: then you have a problem. there is no way to coerce a vector to point at your own data.

Comment: you need to contact the API writer and point out their mistake. Ranges should always be passed as an iterator pair, for this very reason.

Comment: You can do it with a custom allocator that uses your array as an underlying datasource. Do `std::vector.resize()` to the correct size and voila.

Comment: @Brandon Sounds better than my answer... can you post an answer?

Comment: @Brandon: A custom allocator changes the type of the vector, so it won't be compatible with the API.

Comment: @Brandon: It will just override the array with defaultly constructed objects without even calling the destructor.

Comment: I was thinking of: http://pastebin.com/1nyHvLbq but yeah, `GManNickG` is right.. it would change the type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can by inheriting `vector<T>` and then tweaking with it's `_M_impl._M_start` and `_M_impl._M_finish` like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct fake_vector : vector<T> {
    fake_vector(T *array, size_t array_length) {
        vector<T>::_M_impl._M_start = array;
        vector<T>::_M_impl._M_finish = array + array_length;
    }
    ~fake_vector() { // let's reset our internal vector so it won't try to deallocate our memory
        vector<T>::_M_impl._M_start = nullptr;
        vector<T>::_M_impl._M_finish = nullptr;
    }
    vector<T> &get() {
        return *(vector<T>*)this;
    }
};
```

For example normal usage:

```
int x[3] = {1,2,3};
fake_vector<int> fake_x(x,3);
for (auto &p : fake_x)
    printf("%p = %d\n", &p, p);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    printf("%p = %d\n", &x[i], x[i]);
```

Which outputs:

```
0x7ffeb42406e0 = 1
0x7ffeb42406e4 = 2
0x7ffeb42406e8 = 3
0x7ffeb42406e0 = 1
0x7ffeb42406e4 = 2
0x7ffeb42406e8 = 3
```

NOTE: If you are using libc++ (e.g. getting errors that `_M_impl` is not declared), then try replacing `_M_impl._M_start` with `__begin_`, and `_M_impl._M_finish` with `__end_`.

Comment: This is not portable and any identifier which begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter is reserved.

Comment: @Dani I prepared a GCC tag for this one. (Knew this is gonna be a hack) I don't create new identifiers, I use my parent class's members.

Comment: The identifiers this is using are actually of the standard library. They can vary between standard library implementations (libstdc++/libc++/newlib) and between standard library versions all with the same gcc.

Comment: @Dani Good point, I will add version for libc++ too. I don't know for newlib and others.